# source code of Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth in VS2012?

Tags: asp.net-membership, oauth-2.0

Where can I find the source code of Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth in Visual Studio 2012 default web project application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code is not public. You can open the dll in the reflector and look at the code
Following post has more description on the package and how to integrate with membership

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/09/12/integrate-openauth-openid-with-your-existing-asp-net-application-using-universal-providers.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are searching for?

https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/tree/master/src/Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth